# Spacing before theorem with scrbook

Tags: spacing, theorems, koma-script, scrbook

I recently changed from `book` to `scrbook`. Because of this there is now no spacing before a `theorem` enviroment. I now want to change this back, i.e. I want to have an extra spacing before a theorem starts.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}

After this text I would like to have more space.

\begin{thm}
Here comes a Theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: What I know is that you can do this by redefining the `plain` theoremstyle e.g. with taking `{6pt}` as first argument. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Would you please show a minimal example?

Comment: Added minimal example and possible unelegant solution.

Comment: I see no difference in spacing when switching to `book`.

Comment: That's weird. I see a difference when changing to book. There is extra space in book which is missing in scrbook.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a provisional answer to show the effect of the following minimal example, where the `\vrule` doesn't add any vertical space, being smashed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} % or scrbook
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{book}{\def\THECLASS{book}}{\def\THECLASS{scrbook}}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent\smash{\vrule depth \dimexpr\baselineskip+2pt\relax}After
this text I would like to have more space. (\THECLASS)
\begin{thm}
Here comes a Theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

---

### book class

[image]

---

### scrbook class

[image]

---

### EDIT

The test file has been tried with KOMA-Script version 3.05, version 3.09 and version 3.10 (TeX Live 2011), always with the same result